# Are Windows programs compatible with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, compatibility, daw

I just installed Ubuntu yesterday on my Asus ux303lb and I was wondering if all the programs and files I had on my laptop while using windows (which I still have because I installed Ubuntu through a dual-boot) can be used in Ubuntu or do I have to re-install them and will applications like Ableton (a music producing app) work in Ubuntu? Thats really the only app that concerns me.

Comment: Remeber that there are ALWAYS free, open source and fully supported applications for Linux that are great alternatives for Windows'.

Comment: Possible alternatives: http://www.osalt.com/ableton-live better to use Linux apps if you want to convert to open source. Or just dual boot and keep your Windows app.

Answer (score 0):

Not ALL windows software will work but a large amount will. However I've had quite a few problems using DAWs in Linux through emulators such as Wine.

As far as I'm aware you will have to re-install them through Ubuntu using Wine. Wine will emulate windows file structure etc. I have had some success with FLStudio through Wine. Midi can be a bit tetchy. But over all it's not a terrible experience. However if your work flow will be affected by emulation hiccups, then I would continue to use your DAW inside of windows. Thats what I ultimately ended up doing. Unless of course Ableton decide to release versions for Linux. Which at this point seems unlikely.

Here's a few links to get you started:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

http://wiki.winehq.org/HowTo

Good luck!

:)

Comment: Please explain DAW.

Comment: A DAW is a digital audio workstation which is a program used to produce music